# HTML checkbox 'checked' property affects style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a small sliding options control I'm coding in plain HTML and JS. it looks like this in chrome:

[image]

When none of the checkboxes is checked, it works as expected but when I check a checkbox, the alignment of the right icons breaks:

[image]

This happens both in chrome and firefox.
The live example is here:

http://shooshx.github.io/happysolver/emscripten/index.html

What the difference in style between a checked and unchecked checkbox?
How can I fix the misalignement?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised I need to mention this to you: Please provide the relevant code in your question, per SO guidelines. This post loses all reference value if your github link dies.

Comment: Well, the question is actually "What the difference in style between a checked and unchecked checkbox?"... you don't really need code reference to answer that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `float:right` from .cube_count

[image: Result]

Comment: Try to remove the style tag in the head of the page. You will see that there are other checkboxes and inputs that are not visibile in your page until you remove the style. The elements with .cube_count class have that float:right that causes the problem. (Find out with inspect element tool)